# Query error pop up in Access DB using Java

Tags: java, ms-access

Im trying to execute this query using Java

```sql
INSERT INTO [list_A] (ID,[First Name], [Last Name], [EmailAddress], [Tuition Paid], [Nation of  Birth], [Nation of Ctizen], [AGE], [Level], [Major], [Concentration], [Minor], [Double Major/Dual Degree], [Class], [Admit Term], [Catalog term], [Advisor], [Term GPA], [Term Attempt Hrs], [Term passed Hrs], [Term Earned Hrs], [Overall GPA], [Overall Attemp Hrs], [Overall Earned Hrs], [Overall GPA Hours], [Repeated Overall], [Repeated Term], [Withdrawn Overall], [Withdrawn Term], [Acad Standing], [Full/Part], [SAT_Verbal], [SAT_MATH]]) values( '203191','Abb','KSE Mm','adf@mail.ed.edu','Yes','Lebanon','Lebanon','20.0','UG','CMPS','X','X','X','JR','XX.0','XX.0','X 
Bdeir','86.8','15.0','15.0','15.0','84.82','92.0','92.0','62.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','0.0','Good Standing','FULL','610.0','680.0')
```

but an error appears concerning the [ brackets

> Exception in thread "main" net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:
>   UCAExc:::4.0.4 unexpected token: ]    at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:218)
>     at main.writetableA(main.java:532)  at main.main(main.java:467)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ]  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)    at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:216)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ]
>     at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readSimpleColumnNames(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)    ... 5 more

Please if anyone could help I tried many and its been 3 days I am not figuring it out.

Comment: "[SAT_MATH]]" why are here two ']' ?

Comment: ohh really thanks :p

Comment: urw! I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

"[SAT_MATH]]" you put 2 ']' there but only 1 is required. :)